# How can I get $wpdb to show MySQL warnings?

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb, warnings

In some cases, when given a bad query, will attempt to run the query, and give a warning (instead of an error). In the MySQL prompt, to see these warnings, you can run `SHOW WARNINGS;`.

For instance:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id = "hello";
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'hello' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, if I run PHP code like this, there is no way to detect this MySQL warning:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id = "hello"');
```

`$wpdb->show_errors` and `$wpdb->print_error` does not seem to detect MySQL warnings.

How can I detect the MySQL warnings?

Answer (score 0):

From quick look through the source it doesn't seem like `wpdb` actively implements any handling for warnings (as opposed to errors).

Proactively you *can* just ask for them as a custom query (`$wpdb->get_results( 'SHOW WARNINGS;' )` I suppose, but implicitly they just aren't tracked by WP core.